# iPhone: install certificate for SSL connection

Tags: iphone, ssl, https, certificate

I would like my app to install an SSL certificate on the device, giving it access to my
https site. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

I've found the best way is to do the following:
1) Use your desktop browser to save the certificate locally.
2) Write an email to yourself and include the cert as an attachment
3) Read the email on your iOS device
4) Open the cert using the iOS mail app.  This will install it on your device.

Comment: Umm, it asks from a password on iOS even though you didn't set any when you exported it to .cer format via desktp browser.

Comment: Maxim V. Pavlov You must have put a passcode long before in your iphone. It is not certificate specific. Check in Phone Settings->Passcode.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is as you said, we should open it on the Mail app, when I try from Gmail, the install window doesn't show, but with the Mail app, it does. thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, take into account you will not be able to access certificates installed via attachments on emails or via safari, you will be able to handle certificates that you install in your application keychain. Since installing a certificate and the access it is a bit of a tedious process I would recommend that you check this sample code provided by apple, http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009558

I hope this helps.