# Install SSL Certificate straight from the App

Tags: iphone, xcode, ssl

I've a trouble finding it in documentation. So the thing is simple. I'd like to install the SSL certificate in order to communicate with the server. That's very typical if you browse the site and you have the warning about the certificate and you can accept it or not.

On the iPhone, while using safari it usually takes user to the settings with preloaded screen asking my to install the certificate.

The thing is I want to use the certificate to communicate with the server on production version. And there will be no browser, but typical table loading the rows from the XML/JSON etc. I don't want to tell the code to generally allow untrusted certificates. I just want to preinstall that one, either by user acceptance or without it if not necessary.

I know the workaround to simply mail the certificate as an attachment, but c'mon, I'm not going to display the screen about this during my application launch.

Thank you in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

This should be done via Keychain Services, check documentation at developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [AdvancedURLConnections example from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html) as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313987/iphone-install-certificate-for-ssl-connection).

If possible, I would avoid the hassle and just get a valid certificate signed by a trusted CA.